# Opencart Add to Cart Emptying then doubling

Tags: session, opencart, cart

I'm using Opencart version 1.5.2.1 connecting API to it. I'm facing an issue while adding item to cart.

When Adding an item to the cart then hovering over the mini cart at the header it becomes empty and shows a message   "Your shopping cart is empty!".

To make it simpler I was using the code below:

```
  <file name="system/library/customer.php">
    <operation>
      <search position="after" offset="2"><![CDATA[
        $this->session->data['customer_id'] . "' AND status = '1'");
      ]]></search>
      <add ><![CDATA[
            /**
             * Mobile App code
             */

            if ($customer_query->row['cart'] && is_string($customer_query->row['cart'])) {
              $cart = unserialize($customer_query->row['cart']);
              $this->session->data['cart'] = $cart;
            }
```

This code was emptying the cart after adding the item. I replaced the above code with the below one.

```
  <file name="system/library/customer.php">
    <operation>
      <search position="after" offset="2"><![CDATA[
        $this->session->data['customer_id'] . "' AND status = '1'");
      ]]></search>
      <add ><![CDATA[
            /**
             * Mobile App code
             */

            if ($customer_query->row['cart'] && is_string($customer_query->row['cart'])) {
                $cart = unserialize($customer_query->row['cart']);

                foreach ($cart as $key => $value) {
                    if (!array_key_exists($key, $this->session->data['cart'])) {
                        $this->session->data['cart'][$key] = $value;
                    } else {
                        $this->session->data['cart'][$key] += $value;
                    }
                }           
            }
```

Now I can add the item(s) to the cart and it's not emptied but when hovering over the minicart at the top header the quantity keeps doubling till infinity.

Anyone can help me please, thank you!